# What is datatype of date?

Tags: php

I cant send the date time to the database because i dont know the datatype of it. Can you guys help me? Im stuck here for like a day or two.

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO user_account(Last_Name, First_Name, Middle_Name, User_name, Password, Birth_date, Address, Contact_no) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssiss",$_POST['lName'],$_POST['fName'],$_POST['mName'],$_POST['uName'],$_POST['uPassword'],$_POST['bDate'],$_POST['uAddress'],$_POST['cNumber']);
```

I thought it was an integer so i declared it as an integer but it was an error can you guys help me? TIA. :)

Comment: just treat it as a string, stop guessing and turn on error reporting and use `->error` to find out

Comment: what in the world is the relation of the duplicate answer with this question, are you high?